# Allow moving through the job list with hotkeys

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

With the new design of having the jobs list to the left and the job ad on the right, it would be nice to scroll through those jobs with hotkeys, e.g. `j` for next and `k` for previous (common hotkeys from vim and also used in other apps and tools).

Maybe even add some more hotkeys for save, dismiss and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the feature request but that's not something we're going to tackle.